# c# get existing values in datagrid combobox items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, datagrid, combobox

On runtime I am changing some columns of datagridview into combobox columns. Now how do I get the existing distinct values in the combobox items? I am using entity model as datasource. My code is:

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = null;
var context = new AdminEntities();
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Take(0);
var source = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = source;
dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

for (int row= 0; row < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        if (col == 2 || col == 4)
        {
            this.dgvLoadTable[col, row] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            //var ss = dgvLoadTable.AsEnumerable().Select(_ => _.Field<string>(Columns[col])).Distinct();
        }
    }
}

dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your code to create the list of values is working..

You need to load those values into the `Items` of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`; here is code that does that with a list of values:

```
if (col == 2 || col == 4)
{
   var temp = this.dgvLoadTable[col, row].Value;
   this.dgvLoadTable[col, row] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   this.dgvLoadTable[col, row].Value = temp;

   // if the value lists depend on the column, you may want to create them here!

   ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvLoadTable[col, row]).Items.AddRange(numbers.ToArray());
}
```

Note that for this we must **cast** the cell to a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` as a normal cell doesn't have `Items`.

In my test case I have used a

```
List<string> values
```

and controlled the datatype of my column like this..:

```
dgvLoadTable[col, row].ValueType = typeof(string);
```

..beteween the two lines above, ie after creating and before filling the combobox.

Update: I have added two lines to save and restore the cells' values, as these get lost when changing the cells..